# How should I package an Angular component(s) to be shared across different solutions?

Tags: angular, angular7

Currently I have two Angular 7 applications created in VS2017 (SPA).

Solution 1 has several components that are needed in Solution 2.

I could copy/paste the code but I would prefer to have one place should I need to make any changes.

Reading on the web I came across Angular Elements and ng-packagr.

What would be the proper procedure to create a component and share it out to 2 (or more) solutions?

Comment: Component library

Comment: Angular Elements is generally leveraged to create Web Components. What you're looking for here is a Component Library. To do that, you can create an Angular Module and then package it as a node_module. And then use it.

Comment: Perhaps you could make use of [Nrwl](https://nrwl.io/nx) You would have two Angular apps in one workspace, but/and you can share via local libraries.